# I keep getting this error about my ios distribution missing private key

Tags: ios, xcode

I keep getting this error about my ios distribution missing private key

When I try to update my app [this is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MmNe.png)

[This is the error that keeps coming up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR2W8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have exported the private and public keys from the original Mac where certificate was first made.  These then add to keychain on PC where you now working.

[Maintaining Your Signing Identities and Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html)

Comment: Rebuild on the current PC and sign it...u should have a paid apple developer acct for this